# I cannot get an absolute url in my yii2 form action. It keeps creating a relative url and then appending the absolute url to it

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I can't get an absolute url in my yii2 form action. It keeps creating a relative url and then appending the absolute url to it.

MY code is below:

```
<?php $formURL = "https://www.example.com"; ?>
<?= Html::beginForm([\yii\helpers\Url::to($formURL, $scheme = true)], 'post', ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']); ?>
```

Instead of it out putting the below:

```
<form action="https:www.example.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It produces the following:

```
<form action="/web/index.php?r=https:www.example.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Read [Url::to()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#to()-detail) or you don't event need to use Url helper

```
<?= Html::beginForm(Url::to("https://www.example.com"), 'post', ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']); ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?= Html::beginForm("https://www.example.com", 'post', ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']); ?>
```

Comment: Your code is no different from mine except you are not using a variable for the first argument of  to function, which I have to because that url is dynamic.

Comment: @sjw0525 Your  use case is not clear, my solution work perfectly in both case

Comment: I'm using a variable for a url but you are not.

Comment: @sjw0525 These examples **are** different - you have redundant array in your config. In your case you should use string instead of array - array should be used if you want to pass route for URL generation.

Comment: Can you give an example?